# Google Charts Range Slider Reset to default values

Tags: google-visualization

I have a text field where I set my values of the NumberRangeSlider. It works fine, but when the user deletes the text, the range slider should be reset to default values. Min and Max vlaues in that specific column.

Here is the javascript:

```
if (document.getElementById("energy_input").length == 0) {
            changeEnergyRange = function() {
            energyRangeSlider.setState({'lowValue': data.getColumnRange(3).min, 'highValue': data.getColumnRange(3).max});
            energyRangeSlider.setOptions({'filterColumnIndex': 3,'minValue': data.getColumnRange(3).min, 'maxValue': data.getColumnRange(3).max});
            energyRangeSlider.draw();
        };
        } else {
        changeEnergyRange = function() {
          energyRangeSlider.setState({'lowValue': document.getElementById("energy_input").value*0.75, 'highValue':document.getElementById("energy_input").value*1.25});
          energyRangeSlider.setOptions({'filterColumnIndex': 3,'minValue': 0.0, 'maxValue': document.getElementById("energy_input").value*3});
          energyRangeSlider.draw();
        };}
      }
```

And here the HTML for the text Input:

```
<input type="text" id="energy_input" onkeyup="changeEnergyRange();">
```

Comment: you need the value of the textbox --> `document.getElementById("energy_input").value.length`

Comment: thank you! I also put the if statement into the function. now it works just fine.